# Русское название для селекторов `>` (child selector) и ` ` (descendant selector)

Tags: css, терминология, css-selectors

Скажите, пожалуйста, как по русски можно называть следующие селекторы-комбинаторы:

- [`>` — child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)
- [— descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

На MDN названия этих селекторов переведены как

- `>` — селектор потомков
- — селектор дочерних элементов

Но мне эти названия кажутся нелогичными, так как под *селектором потомков* я бы понимал любых потомков, но `>` это селектор только прямых потомков.

Например, на [webreference](https://webref.ru/course/css-tutorial/selector-combine) эти селекторы называются наоборот:

- `>` — дочерний селектор
- — селектор потомков

что мне больше нравится, но, возможно, существуют другие варианты перевода.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors. Селектор потомков и селектор дочерних элементов...

Comment: Селектор дочерних элементов  и  Селектор потомков